# Oracle Forms 11g - Email file as PDF instead of TXT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

On Oracle Forms 11g, I have called a procedure which emails data shown in forms. It copies the text in email, as well as create .TXT attachment of same data. The email is working fine. But now I want the same data to be attached as the PDF file instead of .TXT file.

Following is the code of procedure which I have called.

```
create or replace procedure send4 (p_sender IN VARCHAR2, p_recipient IN VARCHAR2, p_subject IN VARCHAR2, p_message IN VARCHAR2)
IS
crlf         VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
l_mailhost VARCHAR2(255) := <IP ADDRESS>;
v_connection             UTL_SMTP.connection;

BEGIN
V_CONNECTION := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
utl_smtp.Helo(V_CONNECTION, l_mailhost);
utl_smtp.Mail(V_CONNECTION, p_sender);
utl_smtp.Rcpt(V_CONNECTION, p_recipient);
utl_smtp.Data(V_CONNECTION,
'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
'From: '   || p_sender || crlf ||
'Subject: '|| p_subject || crlf ||
'To: '     || p_recipient || crlf ||
'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf ||   -- Use MIME mail standard
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
' name="file.txt"'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
' filename="attachment.txt"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf || -- Content of attachment
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND--'         -- End MIME mail
);
UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
EXCEPTION
WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;
```

Can someone please tell me where do I have make changes so the PDF file is created instead of TXT. I tried tweaking the code but I was getting the error whenever I tried opening the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Oracle Report
- Submit the report job to the report engine
- Return the report object and attach it to the email

Creating the report allow you to set the layout and populate it with the same data on the screen by passing the block where clause to the report.  The report engine will return the jobid of the report, you can then check for completion by polling with a form level timer trigger.  After the report is complete add it as an attachment to the email.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since the data right now is getting attached text file, I was hoping I could get it attached as the pdf file instead by tweaking some code in the procedure, like the attachment type and/or decoding of data or something??.

Comment: Can you please guide me a bit how to add the PDF file in the email?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to create a pdf outside of a tool of some sort.  Oracle Reports can create a pdf and output to email. 
[link])http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28389_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_cla002.htm) search for e-mail.  The report call parameters you will use desformat=pdf DESTYPE=mail DESNAME="emp1@comp.com"